# BeautifulSoup get content of a row table

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a code with python2.7 for SEOs. The program is very simple: input a single keyword and it returns the results of a website. After writing the code, I can't get the list of every `tr` with class `normal-row`. The program must print every row into a list:

1. key1
2. key2
3. key3
4. etc..
5. ...

But I obtain only a blank row. Could you help me?

```
import urllib2    
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

name=raw_input('Enter the keyword - ')
url = "http://www.keywordspy.com/research/search.aspx?q=" +name+ "&type=keywords&market=it#/tab=keyword-similar"
r = requests.get(url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")    
g_data = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"normal-row"})

for item in g_data:
    print item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datas you are trying to extract are not in the page you request but injected from an ajax call.

To get it, replace your `url` with :

```
url = "http://www.keywordspy.com/research/tab.aspx?name=keyword-similar&q=" + name + "&market=it"
```